# WMS not visible anymore in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms

I frequently used a free WMS, which is still visible in ArcGIS but since approx. one week it is not working in QGIS. There is no error message, a connection is shown but no result on the map can be seen.

https://geovdbn.intranet.deutschebahn.com/geoserver/HINTERGRUNDKARTEN/wms

I am struggling for hours to find out, why this does not work. Does anybody have an guess?

Comment: are you looking for any of these layers? https://geovdbn.deutschebahn.com/pgv/public/map/isr.xhtml looks like the url changed and there is a login for certain requests

Comment: `intranet` in the URL suggests this isn't a public service.